# ¿Como puedo reutilizar cookies en petición con Python?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

buenas!

Estoy aprendiendo sobre peticiones en Python y estoy estancado en un tema.
Intento guardar las cookies de una petición get para utilizarlas en una siguiente petición post.
Como para poner en contexto, es con una pagina que tiene un tipo de carrito de compras. Cuando selecciono el archivo es la petición get, y cuando envío el objeto a mi correo es la petición post.

No se como realizar el proceso de tomar la cookie, guardarla y usarla en la siguiente petición. Intenté con cookiejar pero no supe.

Toda ayuda se agradece para seguir aprendiendo!

Comment: Si estás usando la librería `requests`, ésta trae el contexto `Session()`, que mantiene automáticamente las cookies por tí. Mira aqui https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: No tienes que hacer nada. Las cookies son incluidas de manera automática por el cliente en cada petición.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Vas armando tu carrito de compras en un arreglo de cierto tipo de objeto, este arreglo lo puedes guardar en el LocalStorage del navegador(lo puedes buscar como chrome storage o incluso en Frameworks como Angular te enseñan a usarlo en su tutorial [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/docs)), para mejorar el performance de tu aplicación es mejor que vayas agregando poco a poco objetos del mismo tipo a tu arreglo. Esto lo vas a hacer dependiendo el objeto de la petición GET del articulo que te interesa agregar a tu carrito.
2. Ya cuando vayas a mandar el carrito a guardar o a procesar la compra, lo puedes mandar a tu webservice (el cual va a crear tu PDF con los datos de la compra y lo va a mandar al correo del usuario , y guardar el objeto de carrito en la DB junto con todas las dependencias de fecha, tipo de pago, usuario, etc)

Espero que esto te ayude a aclarar de mejor manera tu duda.